# Using plotly in WSL changes the font (console window changes to raster), and won't work at all in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've attempted to work a bit more in WSL recently (I've got the most up-to-date version of WSL2 and the Windows 11 insider beta, both of which I updated today)

Everything works great!  But plotly has been giving me issues.  When I run it from within VSCode (making sure Python Interpreter is set to my correct environment), it spits out the following error:

`tcgetpgrp failed: Not a tty`

It then opens a tab in my default browser, but it just hangs until eventually failing to connect

Alternatively, if I run it directly from the WSL console (no VScode), it still gives the same error as above, but it DOES correctly open a window in my web browser.  It also, for some reason, changes the font of the console?

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is here.  I've used WSL for awhile, and never had any issues with displaying plots and things as needed (though, historically, I've used matplotlib...  this is the first time I've tried using plotly, but I've used it without problem on native linux and native windows).

Has anyone else had this issue?  Or one similar to it?  Any idea on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out after a bit of reading on other projects that use plotly.  The fix is actually very simple, and just requires adding:

```
export BROWSER="/mnt/c/path/to/browser.exe"
```

To your `~/.bashrc` file.  For example, for me this was:

```
export BROWSER="/mnt/c/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

Comment: In my case didn't need the full path (`export BROWSER=firefox.exe` was enough)